Using elastic-net only for feature selection
Could we use regularization model instead of feature selection methods and then use the machine learning models to analyze data?
My problem is classification and there is more than 1000 features in data. The data is mixture of numerical and categorical variables. I would like to use regularization method such as elastic-net for feature selection and then use machine learning model such as random forest to analyze selected features, make prediction and find a feature importance. But I'm not sure this is the correct way!

This question is similar to: Using LASSO only for feature selection. The answers apply to elastic net as well.

This is not a good approach, as it is essentially leaking information from the test data.
The resulting coefficients will be overestimated, because no regularization is applied anymore, and yet the data has been used to decide which ones to include. Measures of predictive performance will also be biased, as the same data has been used (in part) to train the model and to evaluate it.
If you want to preselect variables to include in the model, try methods that do not use information about the outcome, such as sparse PCA (on only the features), or create a cross-validation loop that includes the selection procedure, as explained here.

There is indeed the risk of leaking data, but if you don't, then it is still valid. You can avoid leaking data (to some extent) by using a train-, test- and validation set. I think not relying on outcome information is actually not a correct solution to the data leakage issue. Using the full set (even only the features) for PCA for selecting variables would still be leaking data and potentially overestimate performance.

An issue not emphasized in the existing answers is that the elastic net and random forest might not consider the same variables to be important, and then your feature selection step would be denying important features that the random forest could use quite effectively.
For instance, consider this type of image that I have posted on here a few times, such as here.

In this example, the two features are, jointly, outstanding predictors of the color. However, unless you explicitly model the interaction in your penalized logistic regression that does the feature selection, these two features will not be selected. However, a flexible random forest would be able to detect and use this important interaction.
"I'll just include the interaction in my elastic net regression," you say? You have $1000$ variables, so you have almost $1000(1000-1)/2\approx 500,000$ interactions of just two variables, even setting aside the possibilities of three-way (or more) interactions and nonlinear transformations (e.g., squaring) of the variables that a flexible random forest can use.

A beautiful graphical demonstration of what I tried to convey in words. (+1)

Can you elaborate your claim "unless you explicitly model the interaction in your penalized logistic regression that does the feature selection, these two features will not be selected." which doesn't sound obvious? Do you mean the elastic-net regularization will filter out these two important standalone features or filter out the possible interaction of these two features?

@cinch If you write something like model = ENetLogit(color ~ x + y) with the above data, leaving out the interaction between the two features (which we see visually is vital to making accurate classifications or estimates of class probability), the elastic net is unlikely to flag either feature as important, especially if there are other features in the mix that are decent predictors.

Ok so here your had a hidden assumption (especially if there are other features in the mix that are decent predictors) in mind, then these two features' importance will both be near 0 thus will not be selected. Thanks for your clarification.

Having additional features that are decent predictors might exaggerate the issue, but I suspect that a thorough cross-validation with just the two features above (and no interaction) will squash the two coefficients to zero, and they won’t “survive” the elastic net selection. (I linked a post of mine with the simulation code. If you know, say, glmnet in R software, you might consider putting it to the test.)

As you are willing to use a random forest despite the difficulty in making heuristic sense of such models, I suggest that you go directly to a well-designed random forest instead of trying to do (highly problematic) preliminary feature selection. That was already suggested in another answer.
As your predictors include categorical variables, you at least would have to address the problems of standardizing them for proper penalization in the preliminary elastic net that you propose. A well-designed random forest can handle both categorical and continuous predictors directly, take advantage of potential unsuspected interactions, and will minimize overfitting if you let it learn slowly.
At this point you have 3 answers from different perspectives. Why not see for yourself which approach is more reliable by repeating each entire modeling process on resampled data?
This might be done by an optimism bootstrap. Perform a complete modeling process, including feature selection or whatever else is involved, on each of many bootstrap samples. Evaluate each model's performance both on its associated bootstrap sample and on the full data set.
Typically the performance on the associated bootstrap sample will be better than the performance on the full data set. That's an estimate of the "optimism" of the modeling process due to overfitting, which you average over all the models.
This is similar to the approach recommended in a link from the answer by Frans. It evaluates the reliability of your modeling process, which is the best that you can do unless you have the tens of thousands of cases needed for reliable train-test data splits.
What you will almost certainly find is that features identified as "important" will vary greatly among the multiple models on the bootstrap samples, although model performance might nevertheless be OK. Doing the suggested bootstrap validation on each of the approaches you have considered should help you learn for yourself the limitations and dangers of feature selection.

There is not answer by Frans in the link that you attached!

@Leilaali sorry for the confusion. The answer from Frans is the one on this page, an answer to this question. The link I provided originally came from that answer, and I wanted to give proper attribution.

Yes, this is a known and valid approach. In sklearn, this is known as "model-based" selection, and you can generalize it to other models as well, like use a random forest for selection. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_select_from_model_diabetes.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-select-from-model-diabetes-py for example.
NB. it is only a valid approach if you learn the selection on the training set, see comment below.
I don't know what your goal is, but you can also immediately use a random forest classifier. This algorithm has a built-in mechanism for selecting features. In terms of predictive performance, I would guess it's going to be more effective to not do this in two steps.

This is a known but not a valid approach, for reasons given by Frans.

The suggestion to go straight to random forest does make sense, although it should be structured to estimate class probabilities rather than a classification based on an arbitrary (and often hidden) choice of a probability cutoff.
